# Can't center text in a fixed position column

Tags: css, css-position

I'm trying to make a basic 3-column blog template. The left column will be fixed, have a title at the top, profile pic below that, and nav links below while the content to the right will scroll. I can't center the title in the left div; I think there's conflict between centering using margin: 0 auto with the position: fixed of the column.

CSS

```
#container {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    z-index: -99999;
}

#sideLeft-bar { 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 100%;
    color: #646f7b;
    background-color: #363f48;
    position: relative;
    position: fixed;
}

div#title {
    width: 300px;
    color: #FF4000;
    font-size: 200%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

img#resize-profile {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 170px 20px 0 40px;
    z-index: 99999;
    position: fixed;
}

div#nav-left {
    padding: 400px 20px 40px 40px;
    color: #646f7b;
    font-size: 125%;
    margin: 0 0 0.75 0;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    position: absolute;
    position: fixed;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 650px;
    left: 300px;
    padding: 30px;
    color: #505050;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5em; 
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container"> <!--BEGIN OUTER DIV-->
    <div id="sideLeft-bar">
        <div id="title">
            <p>
                Love Sosa
            </p>
        </div>
    </div> <!--creates fixed sidebar-->

    <img id="resize-profile" src="images/profile.png">

    <div id="nav-left">
        <ul>
            <li>These</li>
            <li>Skitches</li>
            <li>Love</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
            <p>
                some content
            </p>
    </div>

        <div id="sideRight-bar">
            Stuff in here
        </div>
</div>
```

A couple of notes:

1.) This is going to be the only template available when a user signs up for the blog. The reason I use so much position fixed is that I don't want the content to move the position of anything (EX: A person has a title that takes two lines - I don't want their profile pic and navigation be moved down)

2.) The content (title, profile pic, nav links) is positioned directly with sideBar-left but I  gave them

3.) I'd restart this from scratch and try again, but I'd like to know what direction to go in because floats, positions, and how position breaks margin is screwing with my head.

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/2m394zjtdj5505k/Screenshot%202014-02-17%2011.32.09.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-align: center` the `div#title`

```
div#title {
    width: 300px;
    color: #FF4000;
    font-size: 200%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, so simple. I was so engrossed with a tutorial discussing block level stuff that the inline/content level manipulation didn't even come to mind. Thanks. I'll mark your answer correct but I'd still like input on note #3 about floats, fixed position, and all that.

Comment: @SeanDominguez The input I can give is I can tell that you're setting fixed positioning multiple times. What I'd recommend is everything that should be fixed put inside of `#sideLeft-bar`. Also use `box-sizing: border-box`. This allows you to set an element to have `width: 300px` and when you do `padding: 20px` it doesn't throw off the width to `340px`—it'll apply the padding inside. Here's a simplistic approach to what you were trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/jonsuh/C5aDB/

Answer (score 2):

Block elements are width 100% by default and inline elements are their natural widths by default. For the most part, you want to declare `text-align: center;` on the parent of the text. You can also center your portrait that way, by making it `display: inline-block;`

A major problem you are going to run into, is that almost all touch devices, or rather, the browser's on touch devices, don't understand fixed positioning very well. If you try and scroll this on a new style touchy desktop computer or tablet, the fixed positioning is going to jump all around and look really terrible and buggy.

Also, you should think about maybe making this mobile first - and responsive.

You can test for touch events with modernizr and basically say, if there are no touch events... then I can pretty much assume it's a standard desktop that has a mouse etc, and in that case only - make the elements you want fixed.

You aren't just making the site for today - and in a year or so, who knows what devices will be like, so I suggest you take a step back and really dig into positioning and learn how relative and absolute work together, and how floats work.

I drew up the modern take on what you are trying to do. I hope it's helpful. Good luck.

http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/b3kWR/

Comment: This is great input and had no idea that fixed position did that to touch devices, though it makes sense. The sample view you provided is exactly what I'd like it to do on mobile as well. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing. Take it slow. This stuff isn't as hard as everyone makes it by using bootstrap and tons of crutches. *and note that modernizr was included in the side panel of that jsfiddle. I messed around with it a bit more here: http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/Lfdtb  - to change the styles for when it wasn't fixed.

Answer (score 1):

A quick input to point 1 in your question. If the user has the title more than two lines it will overly to the div on the right. You need to set the *height* and the `overflow: hidden` in order to prevent that. But I'm sure that you would come up with that.

Another point is that you have used *padding* to position your elements horizontally. With such design it may not have a much implication, however setting the *height* of those elements is a better practice.

Regarding the point nr3, in your design with the *fix-width* layout it may be sufficient, however *float* my not be the best choice, you could have a look on `display: inline-block` which could add a flexibility for future intervention to the layout and get you ingrain a good css design practice.

I am not an expert, however I think my suggestions will help you.